# WCF no endpoint listening for larger files

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have a WCF 4.0 service deployed on a 2K8R2 dev server and hosted under IIS 7.5.  I'm calling it locally from a test app (WPF).  I'm running into a problem sending largish files (via a byte array) where I get the following error when attempting to send a 23MB (or larger) file.

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http:///FileStorageClone/FileStorage.svc that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Up to a 19MB works fine.  I've upped the timeout settings and set max buffer, received message and array sizes all at 2GB in the web.config file.  The exception is thrown almost immediately (not long enough to have timed out).

It's running using basicHttpBinding, though as that's solidified next steps will be other binding types.

I first worked out the connections with small files, then moved to larger.  At 64KB I ran into max buffer and received message sizes.  At 4MB I learned I needed to bump up the httpRuntime under system.Web from the default 4GB value.

It feels like an IIS or site-level issue to me.  Any idea where I may be missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like this is a setting more at the IIS level.  Setting requestFiltering in the web.config or via appcmd.exe are two viable options.  In the web.config, the following example sets the limit to 2.2 billion bytes:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering> 
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2200000000" /> 
      </requestFiltering> 
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks to:  http://www.dantor.com/support/misc/web-config-requestFiltering-user-agent.aspx

Also, via appcmd.exe, see: http://forums.iis.net/t/1066272.aspx

Comment: WIth http it was working fine but after certificate is installed it is not working for big files like 200MB+ files. 
What should be in settings?

Comment: @MuzammilTamboli I don't think the cert should impact size limits, but I'm no expert.  I'd guess something else was changed around the same time???  Have you narrowed down to it being right around 200MB where the limit is?